# send Email HTML/HTML5

Tags: html, email

A friend of mine has to send a normal email **using ONLY** HTML/HTML5 (or CSS/CSS3, but that will be of little use for this problem) for his school.
His classmates already said that can't be done without mailto: etc., but the teacher insisted it was possible. What do you guys of Stackoverflow think? We read about setting up you own smtp-client, but there was no example and we are not experienced with HTML5.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

If you guys think you know a way to fool the teacher, for example use ServerSide Scripting without let the teacher know, we'll accept it as well ;).

Edit 2:
I was unclear in the question; the prblem is to SEND an email without mailto: etc. using HTML, not an email containing HTML

Comment: It's possible, but hacky. The answer is [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467395/can-i-use-html5-to-send-a-client-side-email

Comment: Could you give us a link to an example? We did read that one already but did not understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be cross-protocol hacks based on POSTing a form to a different port. With carefully crafted payload and fault-tolerance on the server side you could make form data appear as a different protocol, e.g. IRC, SMPT or FTP. This is obvious opportunity for abuse (e.g. turning every website visitor into a spambot), so these holes have been patched in browsers:

- http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070325/javascript-spam/
- http://www.remote.org/jochen/sec/hfpa/hfpa.pdf

Within intended scope of the standard you can't send an e-mail without server-side help or `mailto:` protocol.

"HTML5" WebSockets are not raw TCP/IP sockets, so you can't use them to connect to non-WebSockets servers. You are not allowed to use port 25 with them, and the handshake required for WebSocket connection is not compatible with the SMTP protocol.

Comment: I now understand it, I think. But how could I find a server that would send the email for me from port 25? (I don't need the URL (although it would be useful), just how I can find one.)

Answer (score -1):

You can send any kind of HTML including HTML5 in a mail.
The problem is, that most mail-clients do not support every kind of HTML message for security purpose.

Read this article to have an overview how to format a HTML mail:

http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/

General rule: keep it as simple as possible.
Second rule: Test it with a big variety of mail-clients because they can all behave different.

Comment: using HTML, not an email containing HTML