# Sending email from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, email, google-chrome-extension

I do not want the user to have to perform or confirm any actions, as it would disrupt the general idea. In other words, mailto is out of the question.

Is it possible to send emails client-sided via JavaScript, from a Chrome extension, without disrupting the user’s experience or adding any JavaScript extension? If so, how?

I get the feeling this is going to be impossible.

I've learnt that there is a *chrome.sockets.tcp* API that may be useable. How could it be used?

Comment: It’s impossible.

Comment: Lovely comment... Could you provide any proof, or backup for that claim please?

Comment: @warspyking: Proving that something is impossible is difficult to achieve.  The lack of answers showing how to do it will be your only proof.

Comment: You cannot directly send an email with javascript. @minitech is right. **However**, you can use Ajax to send a request (silently) to your server, which can then send the email.

Comment: @Richie True, but some reasons as to why it's impossible, or links to them, would be nice...

Comment: A browser allowing JavaScript to do this is called a “spam issue”. A browser not allowing JavaScript to do this and where it is still possible is called “exploitable”. Does that count as proof?

Comment: @blex I'm using a chrome extension.

Comment: @mini I suppose so, what about a chrome extension?

Comment: Even if it's a chrome extension, you probably still need something server side. Many chrome extensions have stuff that's server side.

Comment: Then your chrome extension has to make requests to a server, whether it's yours or not.

Comment: A chrome extensions is really a wrapper around a web page. Not much more than that.

Comment: How would I make something server-sided using a chrome extension..?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467395/can-i-use-html5-to-send-a-client-side-email, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript, etc.

Comment: @mini First thing I noticed was that those both used a web page or some sort of server-side stuff along with it. I'm operating specifically on client with a chrome extension. The second thing I noticed was the first guy got up votes even though his question was short and contained so much less information...

Comment: You can't do it from a Chrome extension; however, it's possible via an app (with `chrome.sockets.tcp` API).

Comment: @Xan Can't an extension use that API? If so how could I use it to email?

Comment: the chosen answer to this question seems pessimistic in nature. I think the OP is wondering about `chrome.identity.sendEmail` or something similar...where such a function will send a message to a Google cloud server using AJAX and that cloud server will handle the email.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To send an e-mail, a program needs to connect via TCP to an SMTP server and talk to it according to the [SMTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821).

1. It is not possible to send an e-mail directly using JavaScript / HTML5 APIs.

A browser does not expose the capability to directly communicate with a TCP socket.

While you can initiate a connection to any port in principle, the browser will "do the talking" and it does not "speak" SMTP. It can do HTTP, it can do WebSockets, but not the protocol you want.

2. It's not possible to send an e-mail directly from a Chrome *extension*.

While the [Chrome extension APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) augment functionality offered by web APIs, they still don't offer you the chance to "do the talking" to a server.

3. It is possible, but not easy, to send an e-mail directly from a Chrome *app*.

[Chrome Apps APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index) are different from extensions, but more importantly they include raw access to TCP sockets, via [`chrome.sockets.tcp` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp).

Note the words "raw access". You will have to implement your own mail client from scratch in JavaScript. [This](https://github.com/whiteout-io/smtpclient) might be a starting point.

Depending on what you want to achieve, a Chrome app can be an acceptable solution. Alternatively, if you need both extension and app APIs, you can create both and pass messages between them.

4. Anything is possible with a [Native Messaging host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging-host).

Being basically a native application, you can do anything from a native host app. Chrome extension/app will then be able to call it with necessary data.

However, this will limit your deployment options if you decide to publish the extension; you will have to worry about portability, and the native host cannot be uploaded to the Web Store; you would need a separate installer.

And your messaging host will still need to implement your own SMTP client, though you have a much more broad choice of ready libraries for that.

5. Anything is possible with an external API, but securing communication would be a challenge.

If there's a website that your extension can talk to that can send an email on your behalf, you can make your extension trigger such an API.

However, it's not realistically possible to bury an extension-specific secret into an extension to limit the use of the API.

You could make the user log in to such a service with some credentials, and then store those user-specific credentials in an installed instance, e.g. an OAuth token. That basically offloads the problem to a web service you must control (or have an agreement with).

For extra reading, here's [Apps vs Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/apps_vs_extensions) guide.

Comment: +1 for a good answer to the question.  But it's also worth repeating that since you're going to be talking to a server whatever you do, it would be simpler to use ajax to talk to a server, either your own or a third party email API service like Mandrill, as suggested via one of the question's comments.

Comment: hmmm, this answer seems pessimistic in nature. I think the OP is wondering about `chrome.identity.sendEmail` or something similar...where such a function will send a message to a Google cloud server using AJAX and that cloud server will handle the email...

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to send an email from my Chrome extension (though see a big caveat below):

- On ifttt.com, create an applet with the "Webhooks" service.
- Choose "Receive a web request" as the trigger, and pick an event name (`$EVENT_NAME` below).
- Choose the "Gmail" service for the "Then", and use "Send an email" for the action.
- Use `{{VALUE1}}` as the "To address".
- Use `{{VALUE2}}` and `{{VALUE3}}` (values you'll pass from your Chrome extension) anywhere in the Subject and Body.
- Go to [ifttt.com/maker_webhooks](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks) and click "Documentation" to get your key (`$KEY` below).
- Have your Chrome extension make a request to `https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/$EVENT_NAME/with/key/$KEY?value1=$TARGET_EMAIL_ADDRESS&value2=$SOME_OTHER_VALUE&value3=$SOME_OTHER_VALUE` (make sure you call `encodeURIComponent` on each of the values).

There's a pretty serious issue with this, though: anyone can discover that URL (by peeking into your Chrome extension code) and use it to send emails using your template. (In my case, I've only published my extension to a trusted group.) Perhaps you could obfuscate the URL enough in the code that it wouldn't be easy to spot, but I don't know of a way to actually make it secure.