# PHP script not firing when 'submit' button is clicked

Tags: php, html

I'm losing my mind over this now!

I'm trying to create a simple database connection inside a chrome plugin which I will use for an assignment.

The following HTML and PHP scripts both work fine in my web browser but the 'submit' button doesn't fire the php script when I try to run the same code in my chrome plugin. Any help is greatly appreciated. The files are as follows:

manifest.json

```
"name": "Demo - DatabaseConnection",
"description": "Demo - Connecting to a database",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "DemoDBConnection",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"version": "1.0",
"permissions": [
    "http://localhost/*"
]
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "http://localhost/db1/script.php" method = "post">
        <input type = "text" name = "name" placeholder = "Your Name" />
        <input type = "text" name = "email" placeholder = "Your Email" />
        <input type = "submit" value = "Go" />
    </form>
</body>
```

script.php

```
<pre><?php
echo 'Hello';
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  // do something }

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happened. I reloaded the extension and tried it again with the same result.

Comment: You can't use PHP in a chrome plugin. You have to handle it with JavaScript. Maybe this answer will be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25559358/4072522

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tt3rB8tocP8&list=PLYxzS__5yYQlWil-vQ-y7NR902ovyq1Xi&index=39     I'm following this video and he's using PHP in a chrome extension

Comment: Does the Chrome console show you any errors when you click Go? (CTRL+SHIFT+J, or F12 and click the Console tab)