# send form via Email a form via submit field with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to create a form for a pre-made form for other people to use, that emails the results of it to the client. The problem is, most of my clients don't support SQL, or PHP, so they and AJAX are not an option.

It should work something like this:

```
<form name="form" action="email()"
    <input type="text">
    <input type="slider">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

etc. Any idea how to do this without AJAX or a library?

Comment: Would [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail) be an acceptable approach?

Comment: @Simon probably, if I can figure out how it works, and then make it work. Where's the mother W3Schools page?

Comment: I don't know where the parent page is, but it's pretty simple - it's all client-side, no backend required. The w3schools example is the entire source. The drawback is that it won't work if the user doesn't have a mail client installed...

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie so it won't work for around 90% of users...

Comment: Maybe your clients' hosting providers have a preinstalled email script - many do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a server side component to send an email properly.

The email needs to be sent from a mail server. Spam would be a bigger problem than it is if you could send an email from the client side.

This [article references](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/229272/sending-e-mails-without-using-an-e-mail-server) posting directly to the MX server but it's unreliable.

See also [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467395/can-i-use-html5-to-send-a-client-side-email)

You can also send the email from a service like [MailGun.](http://www.mailgun.com/) Without doing this from the server side you risk exposing your token to spammers looking for open ports.

A server is the correct and secure way to do it.